# Allow user to download ZIP from Django view

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.9

My main task is to have the user press a Download button and download file "A.zip" from the query directory.

The reason I have a elif request.POST..... is because I have another condition checking if the "Execute" button was pressed. This execute button runs a script. Both POST actions work, and the dir_file is C:\Data\Folder.

I followed and read many tutorials and responses as to how to download a file from Django, and I cannot figure out why my simple code does not download a file.

What am I missing? The code does not return any errors. Does anybody have any documentation that can explain what I am doing wrong?

I am expecting an automatic download of the file, but does not occur.

```
elif request.POST['action'] == 'Download': 
    query = request.POST['q']
    dir_file = query + "A.zip"
    zip_file =  open(dir_file, 'rb')

    response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'foo_zip'

    zip_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out my answer.

After reading through many documentation about this, I left out the most important aspect of this feature which is the **url**.

Basically, the function download_zip is called by the POST and runs script where the zip is downloaded.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
    elif request.POST['action'] == 'Download': 
        return(HttpResponseRedirect('/App/download'))
```

Created a view:

```
def download_zip(request):
    zip_path = root + "A.zip"
    zip_file =  open(zip_path, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(zip_file, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % 'A.zip'
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(zip_path)
    zip_file.close()

    return response
```

Finally in urls.py:

```
url(r'^download/$', views.download_zip, name='download_zip'),
```